# Method on result of ternary condition

Tags: c++, ternary-operator

Is in considered bad style to use method in the result of ternary condition?
Something along the lines of:

```
(node->parent()->left() == node ? node->parent()->left()
                                : node->parent()->right()).reset();
```

I'm aware that code style may be subjective, but I still hope I can get some recommendation as if to to use it or rather write something like:

```
if (node–>parent()–>left() == node) {
    node->parent()->left().reset()
} else {
    node–>parent()->right().reset()
}
```

(From comment) What about:

```
auto& childUnq = node->parent()->left() == node ? node->parent()->left()
                                                : node->parent()->right();
childUnq.reset();
```

Comment: Why are the last two operands equal, theres no need for the ternary operator in the first place

Comment: @stackptr My bad, I accidentally wrote the same one again there.

Comment: You can also store the result of the conditional to a variable. You don't even have to spell out the type with `auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is indeed bad style.

Think about it this way, if you were to find that in someone else's code, you probably wouldn't be able to tell what it does at first glance. It would surely take you some time to even realise that the reset() function is there in the first place, and that it will affect both branches of the condition!

Even for you, it could cause you some unnecessary issues while debugging.

Although ternary operator can be neat for simple stuff, overusing it, can make your code extremely hard to read, not only for you but even more for others.
Would you not rather see this if you found it in someone else's code?

```
if(node->parent()->left() == node){
    node->parent_->left_.reset();
} else {
    node->parent_->right_.reset();
}
```

So please, keep it as clean and clear as possible! Everyone will thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend another alternative:

```
auto& left = node->parent()->left();
auto& right = node->parent()->right();
auto& pick = (left==node) ? left : right;
pick.reset();
```

By introducing simple names, it's clear what is happening. The ternary operator isn't bad by itself, but the challenge is to use it only in simple contexts.

Comment: I really like this solution, but part of me is worrying about performance - but that would be probably just useless micro-optimization, right? Just for my information, how much impact would have creating new referential variable like this?

Comment: It will assist the optimiser by allowing it to not care if `Node::left` has side effects or not, and otherwise be identically performant

Comment: @Davar: This just assigns names, and names don't have performance impact.